# marklogic undefined function error xdmp:server-root

Tags: console, server, root, marklogic

when i run the script **xdmp:server-root(xdmp:server("http-cvsearch-8200"))** in Marklogic Console, i got an error: the xdmp:server-root() function is not defined. The ML version is 8.0-3.2.

Answer (score 1):

I tried another function and it works well.

let $config := admin:get-configuration()

return admin:appserver-get-root($config,xdmp:server())

Answer (score 0):

Probably you were executing the command on the qconsole attached with a database as a source, remember that xdmp:server-root works on AppServers, XDBC or ODBC server.